# how to write regex to get only the users from this string output

Tags: python, regex

consider below the output of my subprocess module of python. Now from here I want to grab the very first username only like root ,daemon and continuew. I tried but not able to write the exact regex to fetch the users only .

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/usr/sbin/nologin
bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

Comment: Please specify what you have tried.

Comment: Please include what exactly have you tried.

Comment: Do you need a regex? Why not just split on the colons and take the first element in the result.

Comment: Also, if you are sure `:` is a separator, then `line.split(':')[0]` would work fine.

Comment: In pythex.org I have tried [^: ],which will separate the string with : colons but how do I reject after first is found and until the next line is detected ,how do we do that part

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil thanks but since the result was in string doing that gives me the first result only ie root in the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not a regex in the first place, as per your comments. So, you may iterate over the output line by line (`str.splitlines()`), split the line with `:` (`str.split(':')`) and take the first result (`result[0]`). This expects the output to be consistent, else it will fail.

Comment: the first splitlines()  converts the string into list and than I cant use split again coz its a list now

Comment: You need to iterate over the output from that.

Answer (score 0):

Use split instead of regex

```
for line in output.split('\n'):
     print line.split(':')[0]
>>>root
>>>daemon
....
```

Comment: cant use readlines()on string. The above result comes in string type